# How to reiterate through an if statement after increasing a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP and MYSQL and have been trying to write a program that will connect to a database and GET information from it to display on a webpage.

So far I have 2 tables:
[`orderID` table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiKwx.png)
and
[`reviews` table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGOBN.png).

In the `orderID` table the `id` column is my primary key and is set to AUTO-INCREMENT, whilst the `oid` is set as a foreign key in the `reviews` table.

I want to be able to display the `oid`, and then also the `name` and `comments` for each `oid`, in JSON format on my webpage, like so:

```
[
  {
    "objectID": "ABC1234X",
    "comments": [
        {
            "name": "Mary",
            "comment": "This is a comment"
        },
        {
            "name": "Greg",
            "comment": "Another comment"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectID": "DEF1234X",
    "comments": [
        {
            "name: "Greg",
            "comment: "A comment"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ben",
            "comment": "Oh look, a comment"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

So far I have been able to do this for only the `oid` with a value of `ABC1234X` (corresponding to `id` value 1, in the `orderID` table), using the following code (my username, password, and dbname are all different in my actual code.):

```
<?php
    
$dbHostname = "localhost";
$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$dbPassword = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$dbName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$conn = new mysqli($dbHostname, $username, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

$oidList_array = array();
$objectID_array = array();
$review_array = array();

$id = 1;

$objectQuery = "SELECT * FROM orderID;";
$reviewQuery = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE oid IN (SELECT oid FROM orderID WHERE id=$id);";

$oidResult = mysqli_query($conn, $objectQuery);
$reviewResult = mysqli_query($conn, $reviewQuery);

$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($oidResult);

    if($resultCheck < 0) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . mysqli_error($conn) . ']');
    } 
    else if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row_oid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oidResult)) {
            $objectID_array['objectID'] = $row_oid['oid'];
            $objectID_array['comments'] = array();

        while ($row_review = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reviewResult)) {
            $review_array['name'] = $row_review['name'];
            $review_array['comment'] = $row_review['comment'];
            array_push($objectID_array['comments'], $review_array);
        }


            array_push($oidList_array, $objectID_array);
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $jsonData = json_encode($oidList_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        echo "<pre>" . $jsonData . "<pre>";

    }
```

This currently gives me this JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "objectID": "ABC1234X",
    "comments": [
        {
            "name": "Mary",
            "comment": "This is a comment"
        },
        {
            "name": "Greg",
            "comment": "Another comment"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectID": "DEF1234X",
    "comments": []
  }
]
```

How do I go about incrementing the `$id` value and then rerunning the `if` and `while` statements, so that the `name` and `comment` appears for `"objectID": "DEF1234X"`?

Is it as simple as just adding `$id++` somewhere into the code? If so where would that go?

I thought about adding a `for` loop around the `if` and `while` statements, but was unsure if that would work and also what the conditions would be. If possible I would like to leave room to add more data in the future, so something like `for ($id = 1; $id <= 2; $id++) {}` wouldn't be viable (if it would even work in the first place).

Thank you in advance for any help that can be given.

Comment: Suggest your first step is to look up the JOIN syntax in SQL [See tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) Then you can get the results in one query instead of 2. That in itself will simplfy all the other code

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much! I was looking at it as a PHP problem, I hadn't even considered it would be an SQL solution.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

You should use bind_param() function.

```
$reviewQuery = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE oid IN (SELECT oid FROM orderID WHERE id=?);";
$reviewQuery->bind_param('i', $id);
```

Comment: And I think you should change that oid in the subquery to just id

Comment: If you want to iterate you should use an array to save the values with a loop.